# jQuery - events won't fire for dynamically created tab elements

Tags: jquery

I am using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs).

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul id="tablist">
    <li><a href="#fragment-1"><span>One</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have a button that adds new tabs. I use the following code:

```
var newTabId = $('#tabs').tabs('option', 'selected') + 1;    
$('#tabs').tabs("add",'someUrl.htm','New Tab',newTabId);
```

(Tab will be added next to the currently selected tab)

Now none of the newly added tabs fire any events such as a click or hover

```
$('#tablist li').click(function(){
    alert('test message');
});
```

But events fire properly for the tabs that were there in the initial source code.

How to resolve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) instead.

```
$('#tablist li').live('click', function(){
    alert('test message');
});
```

Or better yet, [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delagate) the event

```
$('#tablist').delegate('li', 'click', function(){
    alert('test message');
});
```

Comment: @Matt, I could not get delegate to work for me in this situation. It did not work for the li on tablist. but if i create a delegate for an element that is outside tablist, it works fine...! Any idea??

Comment: @Amit: You should delegate the event to an element that is registered in the DOM at the time your `delegate` method is executed. Does it work on #tabs?

Comment: @Matt, No.. :( actually both #tabs and #tablist exist in DOM.

Comment: @Amit: My only explanation is that the UI Tabs plugin is preventing the event bubbling, which sucks hard. Have you tried registering the event as a `select` event instead (which is part of the tabs plugin); http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs#event-select?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to bind the element to an event when it's created, if it's of any interest `.clone(true)` will clone an item and maintain it's bind with an event.

Comment: Clone did not work as expected.. it creates exact replica of the existing tab including the styles.