# Links added via ajax do not have the same behavior as links present in the initial DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this to generate an AJAX call when user clicks on link.

```
$('a').not('.noajax').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  AJAXLoad($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

`AJAXLoad` is used to generate new content to some DIV. The thing is that when I generate new content which has links, the newly generated links do not behave the way I expect from the above code.

I know this might be caused by the fact that the newly added content doesnt have the old property (encountered similar problem with shadowbox addon image links), but I am not skilled enough in JS to modify my code so that it works. Any help?

Comment: you need to use live or delegate or one of those

Comment: A bit of code, perhaps? :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2559990/jquery-events-wont-fire-for-dynamically-created-tab-elements one of many

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.7

Answer (score 2):

You need to use event delegation.

```
$(document).delegate("a:not(.noajax)","click",function(e){
    // do stuff
})
```

or for 1.7.2+

```
$(document).on("click","a:not(.noajax)",function(e){
    // do stuff
})
```

You should also replace `document` with whatever element you are using as a target for `AJAXLoad`.

Comment: why should I replace document for something else? I want all my links on the whole page to have AJAX calls (with exception of .noajax class)? Havent managed to get the delegate version to work :(

Comment: changing `document` is just a suggestion, not a requirement. Can you show what your code is after changing to delegate?

Comment: $(document).delegate("a:not(.noajax)","click",function(event){ event.preventDefault(); AJAXLoad($(this).attr('href')); })

Comment: or do I still need to have original piece of code in place and this is only an addition?

Answer (score -2):

`$.click(function() {})` only applies to elements that exist on the page when that line of code is evaluated.

You want to use `$.live('click', function() {})`

`$.live()` will watch for any new elements that appear that it should apply to.

---

Edit: spelled out explicitly -

```
$('a').not('.noajax').live('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    AJAXLoad($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Comment: But how to add .not('.noajax')?

Comment: Seriously?  If you need clarification, feel free to ask, if you downvote me just because I left a little bit as an exercize for the reader, I get a little irate :P  Added the full implementation to my response.

Comment: `.live()` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7 and remover in 1.9, use `.on()` instead.

Comment: using .live in that way won't work even in versions prior to .on http://jsfiddle.net/f56R7/

Comment: Well, that's what I get for learning jQuery on an "as-needed" basis, I suppose.  Downvote away.